# How does local_umask and file_open_mode work?

Tags: permissions, vsftpd, umask

I had some problems with the filepermissions when local users uploaded their files via vsftp to a server.

I wanted the files to have all 766 permissions. After a lot of trial and error I found out that I had to set the settings like this:

```
local_umask=011
file_open_mode=0777
```

But I don't know why this results in 766 permissions. Can anyone explain this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The *vsftpd* daemeon will create file permissions as **0777**. From that, the `local_umask` ( **0011** ) is subtracted. The umask essentially removes the permissions you don't want users to have. This results in the user's file permissions to be set at **0766**.

For more information, see this article about [file permissions](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/understanding-linux-unix-umask-value-usage.html).

Comment: Yes I got that, I know the trick. But how does this work? Why can't I set just 766?

Answer (score 1):

The umask value is subtracted from the open mode setting. If you don't provide a custom umask value, the default one (077) is used, leading to a result you don't want.

Answer (score -1):

You are getting this permission because:

1) Setting local_umask=011 you tell to the vsftp to set:

0: read, write and execute
1: read and write
1: read and write

That is equal to chmod 766.

2) The value of file_open_mode=0777 are not parsed,

Here you can found a very good explanation of what are umask and how to use it: https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/understanding-linux-unix-umask-value-usage.html

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. (1) The OP wants files protected 766, not 666, so you are addressing the wrong scenario. (2) The OP has a configuration that works.  The question is asking *why* it works.  You have not addressed that.

Comment: Ok, @Scott, edited the answer.